# Fetch MySQL rows + one before condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a time log table where all entries are entered with a time stamp and an event.

Now I want to select all the rows after a specific event AND ONE row before(ORDER BY time_stamp) that event.

I can easily achieve this with multiple queries, but is it possible with only one query ?

**Using multiple queries**

```
SELECT time 
FROM   table 
WHERE  event LIKE '%event_to_fint%' 

SELECT event 
FROM   table 
WHERE  time<'time from last query' 
LIMIT  1 
ORDER BY 
       time DESC
```

Comment: could you post your **multiple queries**

Comment: SELECT time FROM table WHERE event LIKE '%event_to_fint%'  <br/>+ SELECT event FROM table WHERE time<'time from last que' LIMIT 1 ORDER BY time DESC  <br/> and combine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to

- Use a regular select to select the `time` records you need.
- Union this result with a select that retrieves the maximum `time` where this maximum `time` is less than the minimum `time` from your regular select.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  time
FROM    table
WHERE   event LIKE '%event_to_fint%'
UNION ALL
SELECT  MAX(time)
FROM    table
WHERE   time < (
                 SELECT  MIN(time)
                 FROM    table
                 WHERE   event LIKE '%event_to_fint%'
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution in not too nice, but works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE <condition_A>
ORDER BY <condition_B>
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM table
       WHERE <condition_A>
       )+1
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. You are not allowed to do calculations in LIMIT clause. Even LIMIT 1+1 results in an error. At least in MySQL 5.1. that is.